# Bouncing Ball Game

Tags: delphi, collision-detection

Working on a school project and need some help please... I have built a game which purpose it to avoid your primary ball from crashing into the random balls that generate every 30 seconds. My problem is that the random balls are not staying within the frame and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

```
procedure TFrmGamePage.EnemyBall(shpEnemy: TShape);
  VAR
    bOutside, bAbove, bBelow, bFarLeft, bFarRight : Boolean;
    ixMove, iyMove, iyDirec{Negative = increase, Positive = decrease}, ixDirec{positive = increase, negative = decrease} : integer;
  begin

    bAbove := pnlArena.Height-shpEnemy.Top > pnlArena.Height;
    bBelow := pnlArena.Height < shpEnemy.Top;

    bFarLeft := pnlArena.Width-shpEnemy.Left > pnlArena.Width;
    bFarRight := pnlArena.Width < shpEnemy.Left;

    ixMove:=random(3)+1;
    iyMove:=random(3)+1;

    ixDirec:=1;
    iyDirec:=1;

      //Check if the shape is outside.
        if bAbove=true or bBelow=true or bFarLeft=true or bFarRight=true then
          Begin
            bOutside:=true;
          End
        Else
          begin
            bOutside:=False;
          end;
      // if shape is outside swop relavent direction
        if bOutside=true then
          Begin

              Begin
                if bAbove=true then
                  begin
                    iyDirec:=1;
                  end;
                if bBelow=true then
                  begin
                    iyDirec:=-1;
                  end;

                if bFarRight then
                  begin
                    ixDirec:=-1;
                  end;
                if bFarLeft then
                  begin
                    ixDirec:=1;
                  end;

              End;
          End;

      shpEnemy.Top := shpEnemy.Top + iyMove * iyDirec;
      shpEnemy.Left := shpEnemy.Left + ixMove * ixDirec;    // Change pos of enemy shapes

  end;
```

Comment: `pnlArena.Height-shpEnemy.Top > pnlArena.Height` ⇒ `shpEnemy.Top < 0` ... maybe it should be shpEnemy.Bottom?

Comment: When in doubt, debug! Run with the debugger and closely look at the values. What I sometimes do is write values to Caption to see a certain value while the program is running.

Comment: Agreed. A common theme of questions from novice programmers is that they have not yet learnt to debug. That should be your next goal. Learn how to inspect your program during execution.

Comment: I think you need to check `bAbove, bBelow, bFarLeft, bFarRight` conditions. What [window coordinate system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145205%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do you use? Is point 0,0 in the upper-left of your arena?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your responses. My  window coordinate system's origin is top left.

Answer (score 1):

You've made two main mistakes:

1. You are not calculating correctly the conditions (`bAbove`, `bBelow` etc.) responsible for the change of ball direction.

The important thing to know here is that the **ball position is relative to its parent** (`pnlArena` in this case). To explain it in different words: ball doesn't know anything about the outside world, `pnlArena` is the whole world for ball. So if your window coordinate system origin is top left then the far most left of the `pnlArena` equals to 0 (`pnlArena.Left = 0`) and the far most top is also 0 (`pnlArena.Top = 0`).

Knowing this you could probably guess now that ball will cross the left border of its world when `shpEnemy.Left < 0`. I will not go onto details about other directions, try to understand the code which I've provided.

2. The second mistake is more subtle. Currently your `shpEnemy` will not bounce back correctly from walls of your arena. The thing is that `shpEnemy` does not remember its last direction. You need to change the direction only when it is necessery, not each time.

Here is a fully working example:

```
unit Unit144;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ExtCtrls;

// Our shape needs to remeber its direction, otherwise it won't move correctly.
type
  TBallShape = class(TShape)
  public
    xDirec, yDirec: Integer;
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent; AParent: TWinControl); reintroduce;
  end;


type
  TForm144 = class(TForm)
    pnlArena: TPanel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    BallShape: TBallShape;
  public
    procedure EnemyBall(shpEnemy: TBallShape);
  end;

var
  Form144: TForm144;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm144 }

procedure TForm144.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EnemyBall(BallShape);
end;

procedure TForm144.EnemyBall(shpEnemy: TBallShape);
 VAR
    bOutside, bAbove, bBelow, bFarLeft, bFarRight : Boolean;
    ixMove, iyMove : integer;
  begin

    ixMove:=random(3)+1;
    iyMove:=random(3)+1;

    bAbove := shpEnemy.Top < 0;
    bBelow := shpEnemy.Top + shpEnemy.Height >  pnlArena.Height;

    bFarLeft := shpEnemy.Left < 0;
    bFarRight := shpEnemy.Left + shpEnemy.Width >  pnlArena.Width;

      //Check if the shape is outside.
        if bAbove or bBelow or bFarLeft or bFarRight then
          Begin
            bOutside:=true;
          End
        Else
          begin
            bOutside:=False;
          end;
      // if shape is outside swop relavent direction
        if bOutside=true then
          Begin
              Begin
                if bAbove=true then
                  begin
                    shpEnemy.yDirec:=1;
                  end;
                if bBelow=true then
                  begin
                    shpEnemy.yDirec:=-1;
                  end;
                if bFarRight then
                  begin
                    shpEnemy.xDirec:=-1;
                  end;
                if bFarLeft then
                  begin
                    shpEnemy.xDirec:=1;
                  end;

              End;
          End;

      shpEnemy.Top := shpEnemy.Top + iyMove * shpEnemy.yDirec;
      shpEnemy.Left := shpEnemy.Left + ixMove * shpEnemy.xDirec;    // Change pos of enemy shapes
end;

procedure TForm144.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Randomize;
  BallShape := TBallShape.Create(Self, pnlArena);
  BallShape.Shape := stCircle;
end;

{ TBallShape }

constructor TBallShape.Create(AOwner: TComponent; AParent: TWinControl);
var
  LDirection: Integer;
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);

  Width := 20;
  Height := 20;

  // We chose random direction of our ball.
  Self.Parent := AParent;
  LDirection := Random(1);
  if LDirection = 0 then
    xDirec := - 1
  else
    xDirec := 1;
  LDirection := Random(1);
  if LDirection = 0 then
    yDirec := - 1
  else
    yDirec := 1;
  // We must place our ball somewhere on the parent.
  Left := Random(AParent.Width) - Self.Width;
  if Left < 0 then
    Left := 0;
  Top := Random(AParent.Height) - Self.Height;
  if Top < 0 then
    Top := 0;
end;

end.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Wodzu, I appreciate the time, and this works :)

Comment: I am glad that it helped you :)